# How can smoothly I reference images in the public directory in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-mix

I am using Laravel Mix and I have all my assets in the public directory. Here is how I am currently referencing the image in the file *resource/js/components/Layout/Layout.vue*:

```
<img src="../../../public/images/Logo.png" alt="Logo">
```

As you can see, it is cumbersome writing "../../" all the time. Is there a way to reference the `/public` directory immediately? I cannot just use `/images/Logo.png` because of the assets being uploaded to a cloud provider in the production environment.

I've seen people use `<img src="@/assets/logo.png">` but the `@` references to the `/resources` directory. Should I create my own alias somehow?

How can smoothly I reference images in the public directory in Vue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [extend webpack config](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/master/quick-webpack-configuration):

```js
const path = require('path');

mix.webpackConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': path.resolve('path/to/public')  // <-- path to your "public" folder
    }
  }
});
```

You can then reference your image with:

```html
<img src="~/images/Logo.png" alt="Logo" />
```

**Note**

You can change `~` to anything else in the [webpack alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/).

`path` is a [nodejs built-in module](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/path.html).